# Visual Studio 2019: JS files not recognized as pending change while other files are

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have added 5 new `.js` files to my projects. But none of them are being recognized as pending change in Team Explorer(TFS). This apparently only happens to `.js` files. I also have 3 newly created `C#` files and they are being recognized just fine.

**What I have noticed:**

1: They are all newly added `.js` files

2: `.aspx`, `asmx` and `.cs` files are detected

3: All of them are under `Web Site`

4: They are not under `"Excluded"`, they are simply not be seen by Team Explorer somehow

**What I have tried:**

1: Tried to right click on them to see if I can add them to TFS manually.

2: Tried to exclude them from project and include them again

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the files are being detected and automatically excluded. However, they were never listed under "Excluded". I have to go into the Promotion Window to individually promote them.

Step:

1: Go to `Team Explorer`

2: Click "`Detected: x add(s)`". x = number of files

3: Unchecked all items.

4: Check the items you want to include

5: Hit `"Promote"`

Then they will show up in the `Included` section

This is a huge hassle to promote new items every time a new file is added. If anyone know how to "auto-promote" files with certain extension, please post your answer.